# CloudKit Default Container Permission Error

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I am having an issue with iCloud synchronization with CloudKit since the last time we updated the iOS application. The default container is not allowed access and we are getting the CKError Permission Error with the Bundle ID being invalid for the container. Screenshots are attached for reference, the container is already set up for the app and there was no change in the code for CloudKit synchronization.

Furthermore we tested the same code with a different container and CloudKit is able to properly fetch and synchronize documents from the container with no errors. The errors show up only when running with the default container, however this should not be a case.

[image: Permission Error Screenshot]

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Ended up being something wrong on Apple's end. I filed a support ticket and they did some stuff on their side and it started working, however the only explanation I got was "we dissociated and associated your container manually" though I myself had done that at least a dozen times already.